# How to send a image to sky biometry from my pc?

Tags: python, mime-types

I’m trying to send a photo saved on my pc through the SkyBiometry API but it says `error_message: MISSING_ARGUMENTS - access_token is missing` and I don’t know how to fix it.

This is the code I used:

```
auth_headers = { 
    ‘api_key’: ‘my_api_key’, 
    ‘api_secret’: ‘my_api_secret’, 
    ‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’ 
} 
 
url = ‘http://api.skybiometry.com/fc/faces/detect’ 
 
files = {
    ‘source’: open(r"C:\Users\Diego\OneDrive\Desktop\API\img\happy.png", “rb”) 
    }

data = {
    ‘timeout’: 60 
    }
 
response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers=auth_headers) 
 
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an API key from SkyBiometry it sounds like. See section 1.1 below

https://skybiometry.com/documentation/

*Every call to the API is required to be authorized, which basically means that you must sign up and obtain API access keys before accessing the service. Once that is done, you are ready to go coding.*

*SkyBiometry provides two ways for the client to authenticate himself:*

- *api_key and api_secret – by choosing this method every call to API must include api_key and api_secret. By using this fields we can map API call to the API user.
- *api_key and domain authentication – there are some situations when disclosing api_secret is not an option (like using java script client code or flash). Instead of disclosing api_secret, API user can choose domain authentication method. During the call there is no need to specify api_secret, instead user will be authenticated by calling domain, which will be compared to specified in user profile settings.*